# In App Purchase Receipt Verification

Tags: iphone, verification, receipt

I'm having troubles getting a response from my receipt validation for my in-app purchase. Can you please take a look at the code below and tell me why I'm not getting anything in return? Also, if there are any suggestions on good ways to test receipt verification, please do tell!

Many thanks in advance!

Xcode:

```
- (BOOL)verifyReceipt:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

NSString *jsonObjectString = [self encode:(uint8_t *)transaction.transactionReceipt.bytes length:transaction.transactionReceipt.length];      
NSString *completeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myURL.com/vReceipt.php?receipt=%@", jsonObjectString];                               
NSURL *urlForValidation = [NSURL URLWithString:completeString];               
NSMutableURLRequest *validationRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:urlForValidation];                          
[validationRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];             
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:validationRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];  
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSInteger response = [responseString intValue];
 NSLog(@"Response String: %@", jsonObjectString);
 NSLog(@"Response Integer: %@", response);
 return (response = 0);}

- (NSString *)encode:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length {
static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
uint8_t *output = (uint8_t *)data.mutableBytes;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < length; i += 3) {
    NSInteger value = 0;
    for (NSInteger j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
           value <<= 8;

           if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
           }
    }

    NSInteger index = (i / 3) * 4;
    output[index + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
    output[index + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
    output[index + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    output[index + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
}

return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];}
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

$myreceipt = json_encode(array('receipt-data' => $_GET['receipt']));
$url = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";

//create cURL Request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myreceipt);

//execute cURL Request
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$errno = curl_errno($ch);
$errmsg = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response_json = json_decode($response);

print $response_json->{'status'};

?>
```

Comment: What troubles are you experiencing?

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myreceipt); <-- that expects either a key value string, or a key value array. You are giving it a json, it will not interpret the json as you expect

Answer (score 1):

This string always returns 0:

```
return (response = 0);}
```

Corrected one:

```
return (response == 0);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do stripslashes() on the data you get from the iphone perhaps